# Logstash how to combine words separated by delimiter

Tags: logstash

i have some sting like "John-Raj  " I would like to combine these two as a single field in logstash by using grok pattern.

So I want the output as like below. But I am not able to get the output as single field by using \%{WORD} and %{NOTSPACE}

```
"John-Raj"
```

And ideas how to create grok to output?

Answer (score 2):

%{WORD} is alphanumeric and underscore, so it won't match your hyphen.

%{NOTSPACE} matches in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

If you have quoted text yo may use %{QS} pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking how to combine several patterns to build the one value as well.
Found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.6/plugins-filters-grok.html#_custom_patterns)

> Sometimes logstash doesn’t have a pattern you need. For this, you have
>   a few options.
>
> First, you can use the Oniguruma syntax for named capture which will
>   let you match a piece of text and save it as a field:
>
> (?<_field_name_>the pattern here)

So in your case the following will make `value = "John-Raj"` (tested in the [debugger](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com))

```
(?<value>%{WORD}%{NOTSPACE})
```